# Using node-couchdb to query a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I'm new to couchdb and a bit confused.  I have a database of movies, and I'd like to query all (or in groups of 50) of the movies with field `year` equal to `2015` for example.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to

1. create a view with the value of `year` as key
2. request the view with the query param `?key=2015`

Use `?skip=` and `?limit=` to paginate the response.

Comment: I had to do `?key="2015"` for some reason, but this worked otherwise, thanks!